# Visual Studio Code Snippet Variable Transform not working

Tags: variables, visual-studio-code, transform, code-snippets

I'm trying to make a snippet that inserts the last two directorys of the current filepath.

My code:

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/\\(.*)\\([a-zA-Z]+)\\([a-zA-Z]+)/$1\\$2/}
```

So when Filepath is 
`"...\htdocs\projectname\src"`
 the output should be 
`"projectname\src"`. 
But instead I get this result:
`${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*)\\([a-zA-Z]+)\\([a-zA-Z]+)/$1/}`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**:

The issue is the code converts  `\\` to `\`. For example if you want to write `\w`, then you have to write `\\w`in snippet.

The same way.. You have to write `\\\\` in snippet json, so that it shall convert into `//`.

**Solution**:

1. `${TM_DIRECTORY/.*?\\\\([a-zA-Z]+\\\\[a-zA-Z]+)$/$1/}`

or, I think you should use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` because the directory name can contain some characters like `-` or `_` etc.

2. `${TM_DIRECTORY/.*?\\\\(\\w+\\\\\\w+)$/$1/}`